# Is it possible to change the JSON name/structure for Spring Boot 2 pageable responses?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data

I am using spring boot 2 and I like the out of the box featured it had, but now I am being asked to reformat to the paging results to a different structure.  I would like to continue to use the Pageable and the Page functionality in the controller.  I am looking to the proper way to do this.

From the controller

```
@GetMapping(name = "customers", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    Page<Customer> showCustomers(Pageable pageable) {
        Page<Customer> page = customerRepo.findCustomers(pageable);
        return page;
    }
```

The repo used

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long>  {

}
```

Here is the default format:

```
{
    "content": [

    ],
    "pageable": {
        "sort": {
            "sorted": false,
            "unsorted": true
        },
        "offset": 0,
        "pageSize": 20,
        "pageNumber": 0,
        "unpaged": false,
        "paged": true
    },
    "last": false,
    "totalPages": 62835,
    "totalElements": 1256684,
    "size": 20,
    "number": 0,
    "numberOfElements": 20,
    "sort": {
        "sorted": false,
        "unsorted": true
    },
    "first": true
}
```

Here is the format that I want

```
{
    "@id": "/users?page=2&page_size=4",
    "@type": "Collection",
    "@links": {
        "first": {
            "href": "/users?page=1&page_size=4"
        },
        "next": {
            "href": "/users?page=3&page_size=4"
        },
        "previous": {
            "href": "/users?page=1&page_size=4"
        },
        "last": {
            "href": "/users?page=5&page_size=4"
        }
    },
    "items": [

        Content...
    ],
    "total_items": 20
}
```

Comment: @Antoniossss, I made a better post here of what I am trying to do.

Comment: I think you should use [@JsonComponent](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/jackson/JsonComponent.html) to implement custom serializer for `Page`, for example: https://wimdeblauwe.wordpress.com/2018/06/10/pageimpl-json-serialization-with-spring-boot-2/

Comment: The problem about that is how would the serializer know object it is deserializing for.     See where \@id is located, the PageImpl<T> would be defined for serialization.  But, how do I determine the \@id object to be printed in the serializer?